# xUnit unable to output to console .NET

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net

Trying to learn how to get output displaying in console using xunit and struggling. I am using *VSCode* and running tests using `dotnet test` within a VSCode terminal. I have also tried running from a terminal outside of VSCode.

I have also tried running *Debug Test* above Test function in the code window of VSCode but receive an OmniSharp Argument Exception.

I have created a new test project using `dotnet new xunit` and using the following test class with `ITestOutputHelper`.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
using System.Text.Json;
using WebApp.Data;
using WebApp.UnitTests.Fixtures;


namespace WebApp.UnitTests
{
    [Collection("Motion collection")]
    public class MotionInfoTest
    {
        private const string MotionResourceFile = @"WebApp.UnitTests.TestData.motion.json";

        private MotionDetectionFixture _fixture;
        private ITestOutputHelper _output;

        public MotionInfoTest(MotionDetectionFixture fixture, ITestOutputHelper output) {
            _fixture = fixture;
            _output = output;
        }

        [Fact]
        // public async Task TestMotionInfo()
        public void TestMotionInfo()
        {
           try {
               Stream s = _fixture.GetStream(MotionResourceFile);
               
               _output.WriteLine(s.ReadTimeout.ToString());
               if(s is null) {
                   throw new Exception ("ArgumentException");
               }
               _output.WriteLine("Finished TestMotionInfo");
           }
           catch(Exception e) {
               _output.WriteLine("Exception occurred {0}", e.Message);
           }
            //MotionDetection obj = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MotionDetection>(_fixture.GetStream(MotionResourceFile));

            Assert.Equal(1,1);
            //Assert.Equal("TensorFlow-WithFiltering-And-MQTT", obj.Plug);
        }
    }
}
```

The csproj file created by `dotnet new xunit` is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WebApp.Data\WebApp.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="TestData\*.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Has anyone managed to get output displayed to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use the following command then output appears in the terminal window and VS Code embedded terminal:

`dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed"`